# VisualStudio 2013 Debugger Parallel Stacks Crash

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2013

I get a message saying:
The component "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Parallel.UI.MultiStackWindowCtrl' does not have a resource identified by the URI '/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Parallel;component/ui/multistackwindowctrl.xaml'.
when I try to use Debug->Windows->Parallel Stacks from VisualStudio 2013.
Anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ran VS2012 setup again and chose the "repair" option.  (After that the Debug->Windows->Parallel Stacks worked)